# Anchor Links in (Bootstrap) Tabs with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following [theme](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4_material_design/ui_tabs_accordions_navs.html) which also has an AngluarJS version. Currently I'm trying to implement the tabs you can see in the link above. Since the tabs use anchor links like "#tab1" as "href" link the ui-router from AngluarJS thinks it's a new state and tries to transist to it.

How can I use those tabs with AngularJS? I know [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) has tabs but the theme needs the correct DOM-elements (divs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-target=”#tab_id”` instead of `href=”#tab_id”`

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-methods